# Как можно оптимизировать sql запрос в postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

У меня есть такой относительно дорогой запрос:

```
SELECT c."chatId", c."sourceType", c."sourceId", cu."userId" as "responsibleUserId", c."unanswered"
FROM "contacts" AS c
LEFT JOIN "crmUsers_amocrm_v3" AS cu
    ON cu."integrationId" = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' 
   AND c."chatType" = cu."chatType" 
   AND c."chatId" = cu."chatId"
WHERE c."accountId" = 91000112 
  AND c."unanswered" > 0 
  AND c."deleted" = false
GROUP BY c."chatId", c."sourceType", c."sourceId", cu."userId", c."unanswered"
```

Я пытаюсь понять как его можно оптимизировать через explain analyse, получаю вот такой план - https://explain.depesz.com/s/JXzr.
Если честно не сильно разбираюсь в индексах и как их правильно применять, но планирую добавить вот такой индекс - CREATE INDEX contacts_account_id ON contacts (accountId) WHERE unanswered > 0 AND deleted = false, это мне поможет?

Comment: А зачем нужен GROUP BY? если агрегатные функции не используются, достаточно вульгарного DISTINCT. И как бы вопрос - а вот реально нужен LEFT JOIN?  есть ли в результате записи с `cu."userId" IS NULL`? может, хватит INNER JOIN, а?

Comment: Да, записи с null есть

Comment: *вот такой индекс .. мне поможет?* Наверное, да. Рассмотрите также: `CREATE INDEX idx  ON contacts  (accountId, chatType, chatId) WHERE unanswered > 0 AND deleted = false`. Ну и `crmUsers_amocrm_v3 (chatType, chatId) WHERE integrationId = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'`